# What are all of the inline-js attributes new in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, inline, attr

I need a list of all of the attributes that can accept inline JS. (yes, I would count the href tag as such an attribute due to the javascript: ability).

I have been googling around for this quite a bit, but thus far, only results relating to "why you shouldn't use inline JS". I've even tried finding a list of HTML5 attributes period. I managed to find a list for HTML4 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html), so I have all of the HTML4 inline-code attributes...

However, I have no idea if HTML5 introduced any NEW attributes that use inline js. Any ideas?

EDIT: I am sorry -- I failed to make this clear:

I am not trying to use inline JS -- I am trying to stop others from using it.

I am working on a project for a website which has gone years without any sort of filtered HTML whatsoever. We have gone through attack after attack. I have finally convinced the website's creator to let me create a function that will filter out all JS from the HTML. I finished this only to find out that I had completely forgotten about inline JS. I would like a comprehensive list of all inline JS attributes so that I may stop them as well.

EDIT: Thanks to Joe Johnson's great answer, I've found numerous resources for those who are also interested in a complete list of attributes:

HTML4 event attributes:
http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#events-module (Thanks joe!)
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html

HTML5 new event attributes:
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp

Browser-Specific attributes:
iOS:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html
IE:[reference.sitepoint.com/html/extended-event-attributes](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/extended-event-attributes) 
Firefox:[developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events)

Comment: Why use an out-dated technique on blistering new technology?

Comment: inline javascript has no place in HTML5.

Comment: @Fresheyeball and @ jbabey I am trying to stop other users from using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there are no new attributes which accept javascript: protocol (such as href) or inline JS outside of event handlers. However, HTML5 has introduced many new event handlers (on[click,mouseenter,mouseleave,etc] -- these are not new however, just examples).

I hate to beat a dead horse here... but, everything you've found is hitting the nail on the head -- try to avoid inline JS.

Comment: I should have been more clear. The reason HTML5 spec introduced new event handlers (attributes for DOM elements) is so you can use inline JS there on the element for that event. Since you're JS should be event-based, to a greater degree, you should only use event handlers to process inline JavaScript -- no other attribute should ever be needed. http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#event-types-list

Comment: Also, different browsers support other event handlers -- for example, mobile devices do support (to varying degrees) gesture events.

Comment: Aha! Thank you! That gave me something tangible to google for (http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp).

As for the avoiding inline JS... It's funny you should say that haha. I am actually writing code that will strip all JS from HTML. I've got it working for <script> tags, but someone pointed out inline JS. Yes, yes, if it were an option, I would just disable HTML altogether, but, it sadly is not :(

Comment: One other thing, do you happen to know if javascript:// can be used in any attributes other than href? I am googling for this now, but nothing confirms it to be either way. EDIT: Just saw your other comment, Joe.. Interesting :) Is there any way to find all of the nonstandard event handlers, or will I need to google for every individual major browser and device? EDIT: Found one for microsoft: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/extended-event-attributes

Comment: EDIT: One for firefox as well (I think)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events

And one for iOS:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: The worst part is... (except, IMHO, MSIE -- they're always lagging somewhat behind or have already implemented their own "flavor" which stays for a few years) the browsers are still implementing some or all of the specs... along with the rest of CSS3 and the HTML5 spec. It's an on-going process for the next 2 (I hope 99.5% done) years probably.

Answer (score 1):

Why use an out-dated technique on blistering new technology?

Old inline js still works on all html5 elements: [HTML4 inline on HTML5 element](http://jsfiddle.net/jwCmU/) but DONT!

Event the new html5 events work inline http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp

[HTML5 inline with new HTML5 event on HTML5 element](http://jsfiddle.net/3E5e8/)

Comment: Sometimes, in more complex applications, you still need inline event handlers, though.