# How can I get rid of all JavaScript from an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I could use regex to get rid of the `<script>` tags in the HTML like this

```
$html = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is','', $html);
```

So that works fine, but what about inline JavaScript? I figured out I could do it this way

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
  if ($node->hasAttribute('onload')){
    $node->removeAttribute('onload');
  }
}
```

The issue with this is I'd have to find all the attributes, and keep making `if` statements. I've also seen libraries, but I want to keep things small. So is there any quick way? Also any nice lists with inline attributes if I have to keep doing what I'm doing?

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this... For some reason I think you're taking the problem the wrong way.

Comment: Stripping the JS from the HTML?... @Sebas

Comment: More about the reason why you want to do this. Are you trying to protect your users from xss?

Comment: Well, you don't HAVE TO keep making if statements. You could just maintain an array of script related attributes and just loop through that. Potentially useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306543/what-are-all-of-the-inline-js-attributes-new-in-html5

Comment: Yep, exactly what I'm trying to do @Sebas

Comment: But I'd still have to _make_ an array.... @wookie919

Comment: But, the first problem is not that there's javascript. The problem is that you interprete it, isn't it? I think you should double check why your javascript gets executed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, don't reinvent the wheel, use a library like http://htmlpurifier.org/ to accomplish this.

Comment: Exactly.  There is no reason to re-build such a project.  And, it's good question whether or not you are letting users input HTML in the first place.  If it's just text you're expecting, then treat their input as text and it isn't even a problem!